# Error adding users to simple database in php with mySql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to php with mySql so sorry in advance if this is something obvious.
When I try to add a new user using this code I always get my error message and never the success one.
Can anyone see where I have gone wrong ?

Edit: "Adding echo mysqli_error($link)" gives me this error;
"Field 'name' doesn't have a default value"

There are 4 columns in my database and name is the last one, can I add a user this way without specifying a 'name'

```
<?php
  if (array_key_exists('email', $_POST) OR array_key_exists('password', $_POST)) {
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "users");

    if (mysqli_connect_error()){
      die ("Error connecting");
    }


    if ($_POST['email'] == ''){
      echo "<p>Email address is required</p>";
    } else if ($_POST['password'] == ''){
      echo "<p>Password is required</p>";
    } else {
      $query = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE email = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."'";
      $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
      if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        echo "<p>That Email address already has an account<p>";
    } else {
      $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."',
       '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password'])."')";

       if (mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
         echo "<p>You have been signed up!</p>";
       } else {
         echo "<p>There was a problem, please try again later</p>";
       }
    }
  }
}

?>
```

HTML form :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
      Form
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post">
      email<br>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value=""><br>
      password<br>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="email" value=""><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: no plain text passwords stored in the db please

Comment: The use of `mysqli_real_escape_string` is not as secure. You should switch to using "prepared statements" if this is new code you are creating.

Comment: When you get your 'There was a problem...' response... add this after to get the sql error (if one): `echo mysqli_error($link);`

Comment: `echo $query` is a great way to debug you can often just see the error or if not try the query in the likes of phpmyadmin

Comment: Edited question

Comment: just set a default value for `name` would be the easiest solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to insert a new user, but you're only providing `email` and `password`. All other columns in your table `users` will take the default value set on the database (by the one who made it), or give you an error because there's no default value. So you can either:

- Set a default value for the `name` column in the database running a query like this:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE `users` ALTER COLUMN `name` SET DEFAULT 'No Name';
  ```
- Change your code like this:

  ```
  $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`, `name`) VALUES (
    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."',
    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password'])."',
    'No Name' //Or even ask for their name and put it here
  )";
  ```